# Where does this "close question" message come from?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

When working through the Close Vote review queue, I often see questions with this message above them:

[image: This question has been flagged as notification]

Where does this text come from? It's not from any of the "not suited for [DIY]" close reasons:

[image: Close reasons]

I usually end up copy/pasting the text in the message, but I'd rather simply click a button.

It seems that a simple "this question is off-topic" would be a reasonable thing to have as a default close option - it is on other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our site is at our 3/3 custom close reasons, so one of the top three in that list would need to be first deactivated to add a new reason. Feel free to propose replacing on of our reasons here in meta. Personally, I think we want to give visitors more direction when possible, rather than an overly generic close reason, so that it doesn't come across as a "go away" (even if that's what many of us mean).

The generic text in the top banner is used in the following scenario:

> This is the top-level reason that appears when there are no custom close reasons. When a question is closed with multiple community-specific reasons but no reason is visible (in the case of migrations and "other"), this post notice will display on the question.

Our banner is currently set to the site default:

> This question does not appear to be about $Topic within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

We also have the flexibility to customize that message for the post owner and for privileged users if needed.

To see the details behind what happened on any question, click the clock icon under the question vote buttons to see the activity on the question. That will show individual close votes, along with reviews and other related actions.

[image]

(the clock icon is the bottom one in the screenshot above)

Comment: As noted, sometimes, I copy/paste that message, so it may have been me who put that in the "Other - add comment", but I've always wondered who posted it in the first place. I _usually_ see the message someone else has typed in if there's a custom message, and I can select their message w/o having to type it myself. Guess I shoulda put this into the original question.

Comment: It wasn't until last week that it even really registered that the "Not enough information" option was there as a 3rd option. Especially now that there's a "Needs more details" option as a "primary" close screen, that one seems ripe for replacement.

Comment: @FreeMan I just realized we have control of what goes in that generic text box, so if there's something to change there, we can make that happen. Removing the text from the user provided comments may have happened back with [this update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/163027). The "not enough information" looks like a good candidate to me too. If the community gets behind a replacement, we can make that happen.

Comment: Woo Hoo! think this question is sufficient to get the notice & consensus, or should I make a whole new one to suggest the change?

Comment: @FreeMan I'd lean towards a new question to suggest the change.

Comment: Voted & selected as the answer (though it doesn't actually answer the question, it leads to a good resolution). [New question asked](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1645/34147). If there is a "vote on this feature" tag or something that needs to be added, please feel free to do so.

Comment: Man... crickets on my suggested change. :(  Guess I'm the only one.

Comment: BMitch, it's been a month with zero down-votes on the suggestion to make the change and one supporter. Is that enough to take action on?